# How to call method after every 20 seconds in Android

Tags: android, thread-safety

I want to write an Android application which when opened call a method after 20 seconds then auto call method every 10 seconds.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Answer (score 30):

You could do it with a single `Handler` like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       //Do something after 20 seconds
   }
}, 20000);  //the time is in miliseconds
```

And to repeate the same every 10 seconds you could add the following line in the same method

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
```

Like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       //Do something after 20 seconds
       handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
   }
}, 20000);  //the time is in miliseconds
```

Comment: 20 seconds is 20 000 milliseconds, not 200 000

Comment: Handler is now deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and for that implementation you can done like

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code here
        }
    }, 
    5000 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CountDownTimer cdt;

cdt = new CountDownTimer(timeint * 60 * 1000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          
        Log.i(TAG, millisUntilFinished " millis left");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
    }
};

cdt.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code.

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
 // Enter your code
}
            }, 0, 20000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
```

Hope this code will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Alarm manger If u want to do work even application is inactive(Close)

it keep run until u don't stop it.

here is full Example

## url

http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Answer (score 1):

**Declare a Handler object:**

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       //Do something after 20 seconds
    //call the method which is schedule to call after 20 sec
   }
}, 200000);  //the time is in miliseconds
```

-again for **10 seconds** do as the same as above and make **loop for repetition.**

Hope this will be helpful ...thanks

Comment: please provide code which does this: "-again for 10 seconds do as the same as above and make loop for repetition."

Comment: @Anon put the above code in a method and inside run() call the method. i.e. call this method once from outside and after every 10 sec it will call itself. for 10 sec repetition replace 20000 to 10000.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Handler called every 20 seconds and update the UI during every pass.

Code should be like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();//class variable
int count = 0;

handler.post(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    updateCounter(count++);

    if(count < (10*20000)) { 

        handler.postDelayed(this, 20000);

    }

  }

});
```

And function to update counter:

```
private void updateCounter(final int count) {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // you have the seconds passed
        // do what ever you want
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use timer class

```
private  CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

private void startTimer(final Context context) {

    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;
    }

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(20 * 1000, 1 * 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //
        }

        public void onFinish() {



           yourMethod();



                startTimer(context);

            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom Handler to do the job. Here is an example of what you need:

```
public class Main extends Activity  { 
  private TextView txtStatus;
  private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();

  class RefreshHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      Main.this.updateUI();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
      this.removeMessages(0);
      sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
  };

  private void updateUI(){
    int currentInt = Integer.parseInt((String) txtStatus.getText()) + 10;
    if(currentInt <= 100){
      mRedrawHandler.sleep(10000);
      txtStatus.setText(String.valueOf(currentInt));
    }
  }

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
    super.onCreate(icicle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.txtStatus = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
      public void run() {
          updateUI();
        }
    }, 20000);  

  } 
}
```